# WPF `Glyphs` not rendering the text right like `TextBlock`

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I'm making a WPF text-editor using `Glyphs` element.
And I have a problem that the text is not drawn correctly
as you can see in the picture, how can I solve this problem?

[image]

There are two problems:

1. Kerning between letters.
2. Kerning between letters and diacritics.

The first problem I solved by `GetKerningPairs` function.

How do I solve this problem, maybe I'm wrong?

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Glyphs" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6"/>

        <TextBlock Text="בְּרֵאשִׁית" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="50" FontFamily="Times New Roman"
                   FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="0"/>

        <Glyphs Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
            FontUri             = "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\TIMES.TTF"
            FontRenderingEmSize = "50"
            UnicodeString       = "בְּרֵאשִׁית"
            BidiLevel="1"
            Fill                = "Black"/>

        <TextBlock Text="AVAV" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="50" FontFamily="Times New Roman"
                   FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="0"/>

        <Glyphs Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
            FontUri             = "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\TIMES.TTF"
            FontRenderingEmSize = "50"
            UnicodeString       = "AVAV"
            BidiLevel="0"
            Fill                = "Black"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is the Font type,  If you look at the English character one is fixed width while the other is fixed pitch.  You have to look at the width of the character and the space between characters.  Fixed width characters the character and space are all the same.  Fixed pitch the characters are different widths and the space between character are the same.  So it looks like the Glyphs is using fixed pitch and the subscripts are being left justified.

Comment: You should probably also set the Glyph's Indices property. See [Introduction to the GlyphRun Object and Glyphs Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/introduction-to-the-glyphrun-object-and-glyphs-element).

Comment: True, I set the Indices property according to what I got from the `GetKerningPairs` function, but did the font file contain Indices for diacritics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kerning for diacritics does not exist in TrueType fonts,
So you must define your own list of pairs for diacritics, and give the corresponding kerning. In most letters, the diacritics is centered, and in the others on the right side. Apparently Text Block does the above.